# Can one queue syscalls to avoid overhead (in Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

I have read that syscalls are expensive because we must switch to kernel mode before making the syscall, then we must switch back to user mode.

So, I was wondering, is there any way I could queue several syscalls and have the results added to some kind of buffer? This way, I would only have to enter and exit kernel mode once for several syscalls, reducing the overhead...

Since this is stack *overflow*, I am requesting some example C code that does the trick.

Comment: Check `io_uring`.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734931/why-isnt-something-like-compound-syscalls-implemented.

Comment: System calls are the only way a user space code can interact with the kernel. If you want to combine several requests into a single syscall, then you need to implement such syscall. "I am requesting some example C code that does the trick." - In the implementation of your syscall just call implementations of syscalls you want to combine. Implementation details depend on the *specification* of your syscall. As referenced in the previous comment by fpmurphy, some already existed syscalls may process group of **related requests**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I was wondering, is there any way I could queue several syscalls and have the results added to some kind of buffer?

In general, no.

For one thing, *usually* you should check the result of a previous system call *before* issuing a new one. E.g. calling `read()` after `open()` without checking that `open()` actually succeeded would be a bug.

That said, *some* system calls *are* amenable to this kind of "batching". Before `readv()` and `writev()` were introduced, you had to perform several `read()` or `write()` system calls in a row. And `readv()` avoids the overhead of having to do multiple user -> kernel -> user transitions.

[io_uring](https://lwn.net/Articles/810414/) is another example where some system calls can be batched.